# What do I need boundedness for in proving $g(\partial U) = \partial g(U)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

So I'm working on a proof for $g(\partial U) = \partial g(U)$ that uses the following assumptions:

$W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open.
$g: W \rightarrow g(W)$ diffeomorphism.
$U \subset W$ bounded for which $\bar{U} \subset W$.

Additionally the proof uses the boundary $\partial U$.

---

What I'm confused about is why is "$U \subset W$ bounded" as an assumption here?

Comment: What is the goal of the proof?

Comment: @tommyxu3 $g(\partial U) = \partial g(U)$

Answer (score 1):

Let be $W =$ an infinite horizontal band, $g =$ squeeze horizontally $W$ to a square. What happens when $U =$ smaller infinite horizontal band?